# ¿Como obtener los datos de un excel con OLEDB Data Provider?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

tengo un problema ya que estoy intentando leer un excel (xls), con el OLEDB, ya instale el driver pero este no me carga el archivo, este es el error que me indica.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo.

```
 try {
                // CargaMasiva
                string connectString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                    Data Source=C:\CargaMasivaInventario.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [CargaMasiva]", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Es llamado cuando llamo a un boton.
Al parecer no me llama la hoja, CargaMasiva

Estas son las hojas del excel..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y se llama como lo indica en la cadena de conexion.

ya instale el driver, lo que no se, si es necesario el driver para que funcione?
gracias!

Comment: Prueba de poner: SELECT * FROM [CargaMasiva$]

Comment: Le falta el signo de Dolar al final del nombre:
From [CargaMasiva$]

Answer (score 0):

haz tratado el Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; ?

```
 Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;
```

en este link estan los diferentes providers disponibles para excel

https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Si el provider esta instalado en tu pc, lo unico necesario deberia ser incluir la libreria para usar los objetos del provider, cosa que creo ya hiciste

```
 using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Comment: Este proveedor es considerado obsoleto, usar el ACE.OLEDB.12.0 es lo correcto

Comment: Cierto !  ahora que recuerdo, hasta el mismo IDE me pegada de gritos que queria que cambiara de provider !

Comment: yo lo descubrí a las malas un día en las maquina de producción se hicieron las actualizaciones de windows y mi aplicación dejo de funcionar...

Comment: @Mike - Quizás te interese: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2931/9385